# How maxWidth allocates the available space?

Tags: react-native

I have View with 100% width which hold three different views

```
  <View>
     <View style={{maxWidth: '40%'}}>
     </View>
     
     <View style={{maxWidth: '40%'}}>
     </View>

     <View style={{maxWidth: '30%'}}>
     </View>
  </View>
```

result of this is as follows,

[image]

Though, There is enough space first and third item are having ellipsis and so much space is left after the items. If i use `width` fixed width will be allocated irrespective of `Text` length.

How can we use `maxWidth` as per `Text` length to use the available space efficientl?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `flex` and `alignSelf` for using space efficiently.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
 <View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
   <Text>..</Text>
 </View>
 
 <View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
   <Text>..</Text>
 </View>

 <View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
   <Text>..</Text>
 </View>
</View>
```

With this implementation, you can use all of your width-space and will give each of your text to enough space.

Comment: `justifyContent: 'space-between'` will arrange items in a equally space occupied manner, but i want the item to occupy the space according to `Text` length.

Comment: `flex-start` will make the content appear form start position.this is nothing to do with occupying the `width` as per `Text` length